# Is the following a good method for determining learning rate in a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, learning-rate

1. Start with a default Learning rate of 0.1
2. Run the gradient descents normally.
3. If the cost function ever gives a higher value than the previous iteration, divide the learning rate by 10.
4. Repeat steps 1-3 until the learning rate becomes $10^{-6}$.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a high value is not a good idea. Since we are not aware of where the training starts on the Loss surface, so it can easily diverge.

Also, in between we need a higher LR to quickly move on saddle points (plateaus).

 *Both start and end should be at a small value*

A well-known approach is called *Cyclical-Learning-Rate* suggested by *Leslie N. Smith* in this paper [*Link*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01186)

It suggests following a Cyclic path *e.g. Triangle, Sinusoidal, etc.*

It says to first increase from a minimum bound and starts decreasing when reached a maximum bound.

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Paper has clearly explained -

- *How to find the bounds*

- *How to decide the stepsize*